# Facebook Like button on my website

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-javascript-sdk

I created a like button for my website and I want to show a like button on pop-up for users who dont liked my website so I have to detect if current user liked my page or no , I searched in google and all examples are about fan page how can I do it for my website ?  this is my code to show the like button

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>

(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/fr_FR/all.js#xfbml=1&appId= my_real_app_id";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

</script>
<div class="fb-like" data-href="www.website.com/example" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="100" data-show-faces="false"></div>
```

Comment: if you follow FB's steps here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/ they pretty much *hand* you all the code you need.

Comment: You cannot detect whether a user has liked a page.